# How to change a specific Character in String using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string structure like this:

`Exec Test @totalRows = 10 ,@DateCriteria = 'nd',@NDays = -7 ,@GroupIds = '3,4,6,7',@OrderBy =  'DESC'`

I am trying to change `'3,4,6,7'` with any single value like 3 or 45 or 65 etc.
`'3,4,6,7'` can be n comma separated N numbers like `'1,2,3,45,33,111,33'`. These are IDs basically. I want to change them with one single value. So my required string will become like:

`Exec Test @totalRows = 10 ,@DateCriteria = 'nd',@NDays = -7 ,@GroupIds = '455',@OrderBy =  'DESC'`

`455` is just an example it can be any integer value.

So far I have tried this without Linq

```
string[] tempQuery = query.Split(',');

for (int i = 0; i < tempQuery.Length; i++)
{
    if (tempQuery[i].Contains("@GroupIds"))
        myQuery = myQuery + ",@GroupIds = '" + ddlTeams.SelectedValue + "'";
    else
        myQuery = myQuery + "," + tempQuery[i];
}
```

Comment: How have you done it without linq so far? and what linq have you attempted? (why do you need linq?)

Comment: I have updated my answer what I have done so far . @Sayse

Comment: @Fabjan - I downvoted on the basis that it was a "do my work for me" question, the op has since edited in what they tried so I've removed it, but its still not a great question

Comment: What is your reason to use Linq? Why not regex? Or a simple IndexOf plus Substring?

Comment: Have a downvote for no indication you are checking external data is valid. (Cf SQL Injection, XSS, ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily do this using regex.

```
Regex.Replace(your string,@"(?<=')(\d,?)+(?=')","455")
```

I don't know why you are using LINQ for this. But regex more suitable for these purposes.
**Edit**: Looks like you need only GroupId to be changed. In that case, you can modify the regex pattern like so:

```
@"(?<=@GroupIds = ')(\d,?)+(?=')"
```

Comment: But this Regex will replace all the ' ' dounle quote values with integer values i may have some other parameters with double quote

Comment: I have updated my answer. Now it doesn't need quotes in the replacing value.

Comment: what if my string has two values like `Exec Test @totalRows = 10 ,@DateCriteria = 'nd',@NDays = '3,4,5,6' ,@GroupIds = '3,4,6,7',@OrderBy =  'DESC'` it will replace both i just need only groupIds to replace

Comment: In that case, you can just modify the regex like so: `@"(?<=@GroupIds = ')(\d,?)+(?=')"`